# How to calculate Velocity of android device each and every second based on accelerometer sensor values

Tags: android, accelerometer

My question is, when i shaking android device i would like to calculate the velocity of android device. I tried, but failed. By using accelerometer sensors based on android api need to calculate the velocity. Here i have x,y,z axis values based on that i have acceleration convert those in to velocity and updating the velocity in each and every second, but no use. Am obtaining  please go through the below code and provide solution where i went wrong.

```
public class Speedometer extends Activity {

      Handler handler = new Handler();


      SensorManager sensorManager;
        TextView myTextView,tv1_x,tv2_y,tv3_z,tv5;

        float appliedAcceleration = 0;
        float currentAcceleration = 0;
        float velocity = 0;
        Date lastUpdate;    

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
          super.onCreate(icicle);
          setContentView(R.layout.main);

          myTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
          tv1_x=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            tv2_y=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            tv3_z=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            tv5=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView5);

          lastUpdate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
Log.i("TIME", ""+lastUpdate);
          sensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
          Sensor accelerometer = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
            sensorManager.registerListener(sensorEventListener,
                                           accelerometer,
                                           SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);


          Timer updateTimer = new Timer("velocityUpdate");
          updateTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
              updateGUI();
            }
          }, 0, 1000);
        }

        private void updateGUI() {
          // Convert from meters per second to miles per hour.
          final double V_mph = (Math.round(100*velocity / 1.6 * 3.6))/100;



          // Update the GUI
          handler.post(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
              myTextView.setText(String.valueOf(V_mph) + "mph");
              //tv5.setText(String.valueOf(distance_val));
          }
        });
        }

      private void updateVelocity() {
          // Calculate how long this acceleration has been applied.
          Date timeNow = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
          Log.i("TIME_now", ""+timeNow);
          long timeDelta = timeNow.getTime()-lastUpdate.getTime();
          lastUpdate.setTime(timeNow.getTime());
          Log.i("last update time TIME", ""+lastUpdate);
          // Calculate the change in velocity at the 
          // current acceleration since the last update. 

          appliedAcceleration = currentAcceleration;
          float deltaVelocity = appliedAcceleration * (timeDelta/1000);

          // Add the velocity change to the current velocity.
          velocity += deltaVelocity;
          Log.i("last update time velocity", ""+velocity);
        }

      //private final SensorListener sensorListener = new SensorListener() {
      private final SensorEventListener sensorEventListener = new SensorEventListener() {
        double calibration = Double.NaN;



          public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
            double x = event.values[0];
            double y = event.values[1];
            double z = event.values[2];

            tv1_x.setText(""+x);
            tv2_y.setText(""+y);
            tv3_z.setText(""+z);

          double a = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x, 2) + Math.pow(y, 2) + Math.pow(z, 2)); 

          Log.i("TIME_in sensor", "Double val a"+a);

          if (calibration == Double.NaN)
            calibration = a;
          else {
            updateVelocity();
            currentAcceleration = (float)a;
          }
        }
          public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) { }
      };
    }
```

provide solution to update velocity on the device screen each and every second.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't get the absolute velocity by just reading the acceloremeter. How should that work? But you can calculate the speed change, so only based on the known initial velocity you can calculate the actual speed based on the accelerometer. Search StackOverflow for threads witht this topic to find out more.  Further more you seem to know not much about the code you posted, because you didn't metioned whats going wrong at all.

Comment: Thank for your update, here the velocity is not varies if i shake a device, but after some when the device is in ideal state it increasing the velocity like 22 mph, 132 mph, and next it stops updating. Please run my code and observe the changes.

Comment: As I said before, it is impossible to calculate the velocity just based on the accelerometer values. The values you metioned seem to be the actual acceleration but _not_ the velocity at all.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to calculate velocity by integrating accelerometer data over time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7036872/is-it-possible-to-calculate-velocity-by-integrating-accelerometer-data-over-time)