# how to calculate velocity using Accelerometer?

Tags: android, accelerometer, sensors

Hi I am trying to use accelerometer sensor to calculate acceleration & velocity in Android. Everything is working fine, but velocity is always increasing. I am getting the correct acceleration. For getting the actual acceleration, I am subtracting it with earth's current acceleration(which is approximate 9.8) Here is my MainActivity Class:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Handler handler = new Handler();

SensorManager sensorManager;
TextView myTextView;
double intialVelocity = 0.0;
double finalAcceleration = 0.0;
double appliedAcceleration = 0;
double currentAcceleration = 0;
double velocity = 0;
double initialAcceleration = 0;
Date lastUpdate;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    myTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
    lastUpdate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());

    sensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    Sensor accelerometer = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    sensorManager.registerListener(sensorEventListener,
            accelerometer,
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);

}

private void updateVelocity() {
    // Calculate how long this acceleration has been applied.
    Date timeNow = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
    long timeDelta = timeNow.getTime()-lastUpdate.getTime();
    lastUpdate.setTime(timeNow.getTime());

    // Calculate the change in velocity at the
    // current acceleration since the last update.
    double deltaVelocity = appliedAcceleration * (timeDelta/1000);
    appliedAcceleration = currentAcceleration;
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //Log.d("init_velocity", String.valueOf(intialVelocity));
            if(initialAcceleration < currentAcceleration){
                if(currentAcceleration > 9.9 || currentAcceleration < 9.4){
                    finalAcceleration = currentAcceleration;
                }else{
                    finalAcceleration = 9.80665;
                }
                double acceleration = finalAcceleration - 9.80665;
                Log.d("acc1", String.valueOf(acceleration));
                velocity = (intialVelocity + (acceleration));
                myTextView.setText(String.valueOf(velocity));
                intialVelocity = velocity;
                initialAcceleration = currentAcceleration;
            }else if(initialAcceleration > currentAcceleration){
                if(currentAcceleration > 9.9 || currentAcceleration < 9.4){
                    finalAcceleration = currentAcceleration;
                }else{
                    finalAcceleration = 9.80665;
                }
                double acceleration = finalAcceleration - 9.80665;
                Log.d("acc2", String.valueOf(acceleration));
                velocity = (intialVelocity - (acceleration));
                myTextView.setText(String.valueOf(velocity));
                intialVelocity = velocity;
                initialAcceleration = currentAcceleration;
            }

        }
    });
}

//private final SensorListener sensorListener = new SensorListener() {
private final SensorEventListener sensorEventListener = new SensorEventListener() {
    double calibration = Double.NaN;



    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        double x = event.values[0];
        double y = event.values[1];
        double z = event.values[2];

        double a = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x, 2) + Math.pow(y, 2) + Math.pow(z, 2));

        if (calibration == Double.NaN)
            calibration = a;
        else {
            updateVelocity();
            currentAcceleration = (float)a;
        }
    }
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) { }
};
}
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Why are you subtracting earth's accel. from car's. They have nothing to to with each other except for friction.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7036872/is-it-possible-to-calculate-velocity-by-integrating-accelerometer-data-over-time?rq=1 So, for example, in your code, if you accelerate forward by A for S seconds, then backwards by A for S seconds, in the real world, you have no net velocity change, but your code ignores direction, and so you think that there is is 2A amount of acceleration for S seconds.

Comment: You better use gps for velocity

Comment: @ZiyaERKOC: `TYPE_ACCELEROMETER` includes gravity. `TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION` nets out gravity and would be a better choice here, to the extent that calculating velocity by (what amounts to) dead reckoning makes sense in the first place.

Comment: @CommonsWare I have changed TYPE_ACCELEROMETER to TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION, it's saying sensor or listener is null. Please help.

Comment: @VinayKrishnaGupta: That's odd. `TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION` is a virtual sensor, based on the accelerometer. I am not certain why your device would not support it. Regardless, I guess you will have to stick with `TYPE_ACCELEROMETER`.